# How to migrate custom user fields to Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, migrations

I would like to migrate custom user fields from an external USER database table to the custom tables of Drupal 7.

I created custom fields for my users (First Name, Last Name, ...) under administration/configuration/account settings and I can confirm that these fields are created if I go to administration/people/ and click "edit" next to each user.

I also know that for each individual custom field that I have created, D7 created a new table of the form "field_data_field_[FIELD_NAME]" (ie. field_data_field_first_name, field_data_field_last_name, ...)

The specific commands I would like to find more information about are:

```
MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema();
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser();
```

I understand the above command is the default used to import users to the default "users" database.

How can I migrate my content to another D7 table? Such as migrating the First Name from the external table to field_data_field_first_name?

Answer (score 3):

An example migration is here (not my own) and there are some followup comments in that GIST:
https://gist.github.com/893241

What you are talking about is mapping old fields of data to new fields of data in drupal.

You do this by calling `addFieldMapping()` in your Migration class constructor. The migration `__constructor()` function typically has 3 big pieces.

1. Where is the data from. Your $this->source() SQL query.
2. What fields map from what to where -- per field.
3. Is there any default values or further cleanup needed of data. By using `addField('new_drupal_field', 'old_value')->default('is_published', TRUE);` or for instance `addField('new_drupal_field', 'old_value')->seperator(',')` for more than 1 entry per row.

See documentation on these pages:

- [MAPPINGS](http://drupal.org/node/1133448)
- [Examples of Field Mappings](http://drupal.org/node/1412126)
- [Advanced Field Mappings](http://drupal.org/node/1224042)

The whole migration class, and more importantly its constructor, is basically a recipe of what drupal does per-row of the migration.

So after you have your source $query (basically a SELECT field1, field2, field3 from OLD_TABLE) you call the following:

```
// this is like saying field_first_name = old_field1 
$this->addFieldMapping('field_first_name', 'old_field1');
```

Comment: i am trying that out right now. i have also noticed if i manually insert the values into field_data_field_first_name, the data will not be displayed under admin/people - edit..would you know why? i tried manual insertion because the data fields seemed simple

Comment: I'm not sure ... if you do manual insertion you would have to do user_save() or entity_save() with a user array. Here is another small Gist moving some "users" into drupal. Basically you just need to change the SQL to do your own query and change the field mappings as I described above (I dont htink you need anything in their .install file) https://gist.github.com/1051550

Comment: I saw that one too. What i mean by manual insertion is with a direct SQL INSERT statement.

Comment: Hi, I know what you meant by manual insertion using SQL. the field is not just 1 field in 1 table in Drupal. A "User" in drupal is an entity and there is alot of data in many tables about a user (with custom fields). It's easiest to use the Drupal API and user_save() or entity_save() to do it "by hand" or use Migrate as outlined in the Gist. If you're having trouble with the code try like the Node_Import module and get a CSV of your user data and import that. A user import like your trying todo is fairly easy with Migrate, once you understand the migration process.

Comment: i understand that if my custom migrate files are done properly and included properly, then if i type "drush ms" in my drupal7 root directory (/var/www/drupal7/) i should be able to see the migration listed? I currently only see the example Beer and Wine migrations, even though I didn't enable them in modules...confusing. i would be happy if my drush can at least list my migration

Comment: you need the items described here: http://drupal.org/node/1006982 your info file needs: dependencies[]=migrate and list your files[]=moveToDrupal.inc. Your .module file needs the 1 function in it YOURMODULE_migrate_api() in doc page  linked here. Your moveToDrupal.inc needs to make a class that extends Migration. Drush should then see it. BE SURE YOU'VE NAMED EVERYTHING EXACTLY CORRECT. These 3 things tell "migrate" your custom migration exists. You also need to enable this custom module in the drupal admin.

Comment: tenken. I've done exactly as you said and as suggested in the documentations. I've even copied the github example AS IS. Drush still fails to pick up anything, but the beer and wine example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2925/discussion-between-tenken-and-chlong)